# Failing Rspec test of a FactoryGirl object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to write an Rspec test to evaluate a validation in a model to prevent a gym member from making a duplicate appointment (i.e., scheduling the same time, same day with a fitness trainer).  I've got the code working as expected in my application, but I'm stuck on how to write an effective test for the scenario.

Two of my models are impacted by the test in question:  First, there's an appointment model, which belongs to members and trainers.  Second, there's a member model, which consists of profile information about a gym-goer.  There's also a trainer model, but right now I'm just focused on getting a working spec for the "member can't have a duplicate appointment" scenario.  I'm using the FactoryGirl gem to create test data.

Here's what I've written for the "Appointment" Rspec test:

```
it "is invalid when a member has a duplicate appointment_date" do
FactoryGirl.create(:appointment, appointment_date: "2015-12-02 00:09:00")
appointment = FactoryGirl.build(:appointment, appointment_date: "2015-12-02 00:09:00")
appointment.valid?
expect(appointment.errors[:member]).to include('has already been taken')    
end
```

My Appointment model contains the following:

```
belongs_to :member
belongs_to :trainer

validates :member, uniqueness: {scope: :appointment_date}
validates :trainer, uniqueness: {scope: :appointment_date}
```

I created the following factories for an appointment and a member:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :appointment do
    appointment_date "2015-01-02 00:08:00"
    duration 30
    member 
    trainer     
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :member do
    first_name "Joe"
    last_name "Enthusiast"
    age 29
    height 72
    weight 190
    goal "fffff" * 5
    start_date "2014-12-03"
  end
end
```

Note: I also have a trainer factory.

When I run the Rspec test, it generates the following error:

```
Failure/Error: appointment = FactoryGirl.build(:appointment, appointment_date:          "2015-12-02 00:09:00")
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
Validation failed: First name has already been taken, Last name has already been taken
```

It appears Rspec has a problem with the second FactoryGirl object that I attempt to build, but I don't understand what I need to do to fix the issue.  I'm new to Rails, and would appreciate any advice, suggestions or thoughts about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In creating two appointments, you are also creating two `member`s who are identical and apparently are violating some rule you have about members not having the same First and/or Last name.
The best solution would be to create a member

```
single_member = FactoryGirl.create(:member)
```

and then pass the instance member to your FactoryGirl appointment instances so that it instead uses your member object and not create it again.

```
FactoryGirl.create(:appointment, appointment_date: "2015-12-02 00:09:00", member: single_member)
appointment = FactoryGirl.build(:appointment, appointment_date: "2015-12-02 00:09:00", member: single_member)
appointment.valid?
expect(appointment.errors[:member]).to include('has already been taken')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  Your recommended code changes did the trick.  My Rspec test is now green, and my application code works as expected.  By the way, you were correct in assuming that I was validating for uniqueness on the first & last names of members. The Rspec test was picking that reference up from my member model.  Once again, THANK YOU!